# Why is my angular 2 application not rendering?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have an angular 2 application that I am building while watching a video tutorial. But the problem is that I referenced the files very well but i am having page not found in the console of my browser.
**HERE IS THE CODE OF MY COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'my-employee',
   templateUrl: '.Employee/employee.component.html'
})
export class EmployeeComponent {
   firstName: string = 'Mr X';
   lastName: string = 'Johnson';
   gender: string = 'Male';
   age: number = 20;
}
```

The templateUrl is properly referenced but i am still getting page nof found error. Please any help will be highly welcomed. Thanks.
**UPDATE: STRUCTURE OF PROJECT**
[image]

Comment: Can you post your project structure ?

Comment: I just did crude update could not find a better way to update the project structure.

Comment: I am talking about screenshot of project structure.

Comment: Just uploaded it.

Comment: Please review posted answer, if still face any issue then post me in answer's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello can you please try:

```
templateUrl: './employee.component.html'
```

It's path issue. You do not need to add **Employee** in the `teamplateURL`.

Here's the full code:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-employee',
    templateUrl: './employee.component.html'
})
export class EmployeeComponent {
    firstName: string = 'Mr X';
    lastName: string = 'Johnson';
    gender: string = 'Male';
    age: number = 20;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution you posted but the problem still persist. I am getting
http://localhost:59956/src/app/Employee/employee.component.html 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:59956/src/app/Employee/employee.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load http://localhost:59956/src/app/Employee/employee.component.html undefined

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful. I have resolved the problem now.

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful. I have resolved the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

As employee.component.html and employee.component.ts are in same folder then no need to add Employee/employee.component.html in template url path. Also you are using only '.' before a folder name so just change it to `'./employee.component.html'`. Hope ut will work.